# MySQL - how to sum counts by group

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have three tables connected with the following relation:

```
"agency" 1-n "agent" 1-n "ad" 
(agency has many agents and each agent has many ads)
```

I want to get a list of ad counts by agency, like this:

```
agency_name   |   ad_count
---------------------------
agency 1      |     15
agency 2      |     25
agency 3      |     0
```

Where even agencies with 0 ads would be shown. Is this possible? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me that this must be a pretty common problem - is there a better title that could help others find this question easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4a8b/2/0)

```
select agency.agency_name, count(ad.id)
from agency
left join agent on agent.agency_id = agency.id
left join ad on ad.agent_id = agent.id
group by agency.agency_name
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it perfectly - very simple and clear, I learnt from it! And especially for introducing me to SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the exact table structure I have to guess a little

```
select agency.agency_name, 
       count(ad.id) as ad_count
from agency 
left outer join agent on agency.id = agent.agency_id
left outer join ad on ad.id = agent.ad_id
group by agency.agency_name
```

Comment: Good answer but wouldn't it be good to also have 'coalesce()' to replace null with zero for agencies with no ads?

Comment: Not in the `count`. If there is no `ad.id` it won't count

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, since I don't have much experience with SQL, I learnt from your answer, examining the difference from the first one, which matched my table structure as well - I'm sorry I didn't provide more information from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.agencyname, IFNULL(b.adcnt, 0) adcount  
FROM agency 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.agencyid, SUM(adcnt) adcnt 
           FROM agent a 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT agentid, COUNT(agentid) adcnt 
                       FROM ad 
                       GROUP BY agentid
                      ) b ON a.agentid = b.agentid 
           GROUP BY agencyid) b ON a.agencyid = b.agencyid
```